# InvalidWitnessesUTXO

Tags: transaction, nami-wallet, ledger, cbor

Some transactions I’ve been creating are throwing an InvalidWitnessesUTXO error. Appears to be happening to some specific inputs, and any transaction that includes it fails with this same error.

By the way, those transactions are not being created by cardano-cli, their bytes are manually generated, so probably there’s where the error is. Here are some examples of transactions that are throwing this error:

```
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
```

```
84A30082825820353AC8FABB2963D9C5FD2160B706973D70333A87F4B9421BF7404A7EB5AC7A420182582039C885AD9B66757B9E2C1B7F2C816FF67B8D56AF857DC451752926C241F9C46F000182825839015E914486736E665A966C010AE54017593F6D69E6E00ACD0DC6531E8D337C746991A49CEE49ED190F2FDEA52887D33F84F1E7E71F3B415515821A1796433FA4581C1CDA8886F4CBAB2217346187A923B3BE670E42EF5778A0AD7D25358CB44F4D7574616E74546F61643032313030014F4D7574616E74546F61643033303330014F4D7574616E74546F61643033323732014F4D7574616E74546F61643033333535014F4D7574616E74546F61643033383038014F4D7574616E74546F61643033383239014F4D7574616E74546F61643033383639014F4D7574616E74546F61643033393434014F4D7574616E74546F61643034303932014F4D7574616E74546F61643034313139014F4D7574616E74546F61643034323236014F4D7574616E74546F61643034343232014F4D7574616E74546F61643034373431014F4D7574616E74546F61643034393439014F4D7574616E74546F61643033303336014F4D7574616E74546F61643033333239014F4D7574616E74546F61643033343031014F4D7574616E74546F61643034343636014F4D7574616E74546F61643034363732014F4D7574616E74546F6164303439343701581CD517F38DD2C5ACC3347C8E933E2C0185FAFE3BA838F8830000A3C95FA14F4D7574616E7443726F63303439323801581C7DDC646D0E15B44DB03F0F904E0AB6B72E57AA48D2E579CE66366A3DA4544265617273436C75624D656D626572303133373501544265617273436C75624D656D626572303137353601544265617273436C75624D656D626572303238303701544265617273436C75624D656D626572303336333301581CF4988F549728DC76B58D7677849443CAF6E5385DC67E6C25F6AA901EA54A506978656C54696C6534014B506978656C54696C653238014B506978656C54696C653532014B506978656C54696C653535014B506978656C54696C6535390183581D7115EEA1EEAB457FB4545F260BFC84506DFF8B5026E82DD1E516A859A3821A001A4EC4A1581C1CDA8886F4CBAB2217346187A923B3BE670E42EF5778A0AD7D25358CA14F4D7574616E74546F61643033393139015820BBE0865A7AF0500E70474074674E8D45E6FDBB2FC37CEE2F12023F2A15BFEA36021A0003BA25A100818258206395B3BA1098D9855AB88FA56D51EF9CFCA792CDD4701561CCE2FE7E00748C0858401CB6F5B2EBF2D8D44FDA986F479163C4E47586ABDDE411CC8E093EB1AF5281F8561E8219DB9C47F3F842E5151DB65C5AA9DC476CF60A08A40E37D478D1054C04F5F6
```

Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually related to the Multiasset sorting. I was creating the transaction and when it got into Emurgo/serialization library code the multiasset was being reordered before the transaction was signed. Therefore, I was receiving a signature that was invalid to the transaction I primarily sent.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a UTXO without including the witness signature of the private key that owns it.

You should sign the raw transaction with the key and include the witness in the final transaction.

If you are using UTXOs from multiple keys, you will need to sign the raw tx with all the keys and include all the corresponding witnesses in the final transaction.